# JavaScript code not working properly in Odoo v14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, checkbox, odoo

Good day, I hope you are doing well.

I am developing a new module in odoo, it's simple Parc Module.

**I want to disable the checkboxes when the value of Stock is 0.**

I wrote this code :

```
odoo.define('de_alfa_parc.CustomListRenderer', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
    ListRenderer.include({
        _renderRow: function (record) {
            var self = this;
            var tr = this._super(record);
            var categ = ['Maintenance','Installation','Transport',"Volume d'impression"]
            console.log(record.data.small_category_name_field);
            tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('disabled', record.data.stock <= 0 && !categ.includes(record.data.small_category_name_field) == true);
            return tr;
        },
    });
});
```

it's working well when I open the view and the checkboxes are disabled when the stock value is 0

**BUT !!**

**When I touch any line, or modify any value, all the checkboxes become automatically enabled and I need to refresh the page so the script works again**, can you please assit ?

Please to see the screnshots for more details

[The code is working here on first load of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8hLB.png)
[I try to update the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRAS.png)
[The code stops working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvQEA.png)
[After refreshing the page, the code works again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEDbI.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on a row to edit, Odoo will set the row mode and change the [selectors](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js#L468-L472) state depending on the edit mode

To keep the selectors disabled, you need to change how the [_disableRecordSelectors and _enableRecordSelectors](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js#L642-L650) functions behave

They are defined inside the editable list renderer as follows:

```
_disableRecordSelectors: function () {
    this.$('.o_list_record_selector input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
},

_enableRecordSelectors: function () {
    this.$('.o_list_record_selector input').attr('disabled', false);
},
```

Instead of overriding the list renderer, you can define a new list renderer that you can apply only on a specific list using the `js_class` attribute

***Example:***

```
odoo.define('MODULE_NAME.custom_tree_renderer', function (require) {
"use strict";
    // var core = require('web.core');
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');

    var CustomListRenderer = ListRenderer.extend({
        _renderRow: function (record) {
            ...
        },

        _disableRecordSelectors: function () {
            ...
        },

        _enableRecordSelectors: function () {
            ...
        },

    });

    var CustomListView = ListView.extend({
        config: _.extend({}, ListView.prototype.config, {
            Renderer: CustomListRenderer,
        }),
    });

    viewRegistry.add('custom_tree_renderer', CustomListView);
});
```

To use the custom list render, you need to set the `js_class` attribute on the `tree` tag:

```
<tree js_class="custom_tree_renderer">
```

Comment: want to thank you for your assistance.
I’ve copied your code, changed the MODULE_NAME
set the js_class
added my function :

_renderRow: function (record) {
          HERE
        },

Unfortunately, the page stops loading.

Sorry I am not familiar with JavaScript, I just wanted to do the trick for my End Of Study project.
What should I write inside theses functions please :
_disableRecordSelectors: function () {
            ...
        },

        _enableRecordSelectors: function () {
            ...
        },

Comment: As an example, try to remove the code inside those functions so Odoo will not disable/enable the selectors